# discord not working on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, 22.04

I download the discord .deb file and I try to install it by several ways.

```
sudo dpkg -i ./discord-0.0.18.deb
```

then terminal looks like

```
(Reading database ... 255328 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./discord-0.0.18.deb ...
Unpacking discord (0.0.18) over (0.0.18) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package discord (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 discord
```

And I tried using

```
sudo apt-get install ./discord-0.0.18.deb
```

Then

```
(Reading database ... 255328 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./discord-0.0.18.deb ...
Unpacking discord (0.0.18) over (0.0.18) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package discord (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 discord
```

I tried to install the missing package using

```
sudo apt install libc++1
```

But Terminal looks like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc++1 : Depends: libc++1-14 (>= 14~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Are you open to alternatives to the deb package? The [Discord snap](https://snapcraft.io/discord) is very easy to install and works well.

Comment: I installed using snap and it is working very well.

Answer (score 1):

Discord can be installed via snap

##### Install snap

probably already instaled
`sudo apt install snapd-xdg-open`

##### Install discord

`sudo snap install discord`